# Constrained linear regression with pyspark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml

I want to do a multiple linear regression in pyspark where

1. **y** = **Bx** = b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3  (assume the number of features is 3)
2. Sum of weights in vector **B** equals to 1;
3. Each weight is non-negative and no greater than 1.

I learned how to do so in python with `scipy.optimize.minimize` through these two questions: [constrained linear regression / quadratic programming python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852921/constrained-linear-regression-quadratic-programming-python) & [Simple linear regression with constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589230/simple-linear-regression-with-constraint).

I also knew that in Spark, simple linear regression can be done with library `pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression`, but didn't find which parameters I can tweak to meet the constraints.

I tried to create a UDF in spark and use the `scipy` method in python (following this post [Pyspark dataframe: how to apply scipy.optimize function by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247428/pyspark-dataframe-how-to-apply-scipy-optimize-function-by-group?rq=1)). Put aside the slow performance, the weights also turned out to be wrong.

Below is a simplified example for testing:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x1 = np.array([5.2, 5.3, 4.2, 3.9])
x2 = np.array([4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 3.1])
x3 = np.array([5.4, 6.2, 4.9, 4.7])

m = np.vstack([x1,x2,x3])
y = np.array([5.3, 4.9, 5.6, 4.1])
startval = np.zeros(m.shape[0])

cons = ({'type': 'eq',
          'fun' : lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0})
bnds = [(0, 1) for i in range(m.shape[0])]

def loss_ols(x):
    return np.sum(np.square(np.linalg.norm(np.dot(x, m) - y, 2)))

res = minimize(loss_ols, startval, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons,
                bounds=bnds, options={'disp': True})
print('Weights: {}.'.format(np.round(res.x,2)))
```

The resulted weights are `[0.19 0.43 0.38]`. But the results in spark is `[0.9999999999999977, 1.2212453270876722E-15, 1.2212453270876722E-15]` I think there must be something wrong with my Spark code. So would like to hear from your opinions on whether

My questions are:

1. Is there any function in the Spark ML library where the constraints and bounds can be specified?
2. If not, could you please share a faster and correct way of mapping the `minimize` function?